# .htaccess RewriteCond regex not matching

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can somebody please explain to me why https://www.example.com/meetings-and-events/soho doesn't match:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com\/meetings-and-events\/soho$ [NC]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` only matches domain name in the request. To match URI, use `%{REQUEST_URI}` as this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/meetings-and-events/soho/?$ [NC]
```